# Obtain "Media State" of network adapters in windows using java?

Tags: java, windows, network-interface

How can I obtain the media state of a network adapter in windows? I've searched a bit and it doesn't look like the java.net.NetworkInterface class provides this ability, which makes sense as it appears to be a windows concept that doesn't even apply to all adapters. When I run ipconfig I get something like the following:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 5:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : BlahBlah.Blah
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.113.44
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.113.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 8:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : BlahBlah.Blah
```

And if I use the script found at [Can anyone explain why Java GetNetworkInterfaces returns so many interfaces on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953460/can-anyone-explain-why-java-getnetworkinterfaces-returns-so-many-interfaces-on-w/5954098#5954098) to obtain details from these adapters (with the others removed) I get something like the following:

```
Display name: Software Loopback Interface 1
Name: lo
InetAddress: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
InetAddress: /127.0.0.1
Up? true
Loopback? true
PointToPoint? false
Supports multicast? true
Virtual? false
Hardware address: []
MTU: -1

Display name: Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection #2
Name: eth13
InetAddress: /172.16.4.29
Up? false
Loopback? false
PointToPoint? false
Supports multicast? true
Virtual? false
Hardware address: [60, -105, 14, -77, -123, 110]
MTU: 1500

Display name: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 #3
Name: net11
InetAddress: /192.168.113.44
Up? false
Loopback? false
PointToPoint? false
Supports multicast? true
Virtual? false
Hardware address: [60, -105, 14, -77, -123, 110]
MTU: 1500
```

Thoughts on how I can determine if the ethernet adapter is "Media disconnected"?

Comment: Is there a difference between the Media Disconnected property in windows and the isUP property on the NetworkInterface?

Comment: There is. In the output I added it shows a disconnected (but not disabled) ethernet adapter, as well as a connected wireless adapter. They both return false for isUp(), so I'm really not sure what the "Up" parameter indicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference of the below snippet. Basically `!networkInterface.isUp()` should do the trick for you.

```
List<NetworkInterface> nic = new ArrayList<>();
interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement();
    if (!networkInterface.isUp())
        continue;
    nic.add(networkinterface);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at the comments on the initial post you'll see that isUp != media state and doesn't solve the problem.